# Java, Performance issues with ESAPI validator

Tags: java, performance, validation, esapi

In our java web application, we are using ESAPI validator for validating urls. It does what we are expecting, but takes too much time for getting results (especially for wrong urls). For some wrong urls it takes more than two minutes for getting result. Here is the my method that validates URL using ESAPI validator.

```
    public static boolean isSecuredURL(String value) {


    return ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URL", value, "URL", 255, false);

}
```

I fear frequent use of this method will affect performance of my application. Is there any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

1. Analyze the regex pattern being used for validation. What regex pattern you are using ?
2. Debug the Validator code.
3. Also, you can use single instance of validator object. The encoder is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks Amit.
I am using default regex pattern comes with validation.properties. 
It is Validator.URL=^(ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\?\\,\\:\\'\\/\\\\\\+=&amp;%\\$#_]*)?$. 

Is it a good option to save validator instance as a singleton Object? Is there any negative sides for keeping that instance forever in application?singleton object?

Comment: Are you supporting FTP ? Would not any of this suffice  ? Validator.HTTPURI=^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-=\\*\\.\\?;,+\\/:&_ ]*$
Validator.HTTPURL=^.*$   . I checked the internal code , it seems any how, you always get the singleton instance of DefaultValidator from ESPAI. You can just save the Validator initialization cost before serving your first request.

Answer (score 0):

Two part answer:  Answering your core question--performance--this isn't an ESAPI problem.  I've deployed esapi to at least 6 production applications in my career and have never had an issue like what you're describing.  My guess is that ESAPI has uncovered some bad Exception handling/re-throwing in your application, especially if you're doing anything funky with RuntimeExceptions. ESAPI's main canonicalize exception, `IntrusionException` inherits from `java.lang.RuntimeException`.  Since its a runtime exception, it might twirl around in stack unwinding until the system finally finds a handler that can deal with it.  My suggestion is to use a profiling tool like visualJVM or Jprofiler to find *exactly* what your problem is.  Now... to URL validation.

First off, be VERY wary that using esapi to "validate" URLs has [known pitfalls.](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/detail?id=258)

The biggest pitfall however is the choice to use a regular expression to validate something as complicated as a URL.  Different parts of a URL have different parsing rules:

```
[scheme:][user-info@][host][:port][path][?query][#fragment]
```

So, right off the bat, ESAPI 2.0 makes a simplification that it really shouldn't:  A piece of URL data is just a string that we can do stuff to.

If you want to capture this in a regular expression, [this is what that monster looks like.](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

Further, you need to be wary of the finer business rules behind a URL.  Can you restrict the URL in any way?  That's a policy question and beyond scope, but it does dictate what you can do.  This is the method that I follow:

What you're going to want to do is follow this procedure:

1. Use `java.net.URI` to break apart and do an initial validation pass.  This will handle breaking the URI into an RFC-3986 compliant regex.
2. According to the URI parsing rules given above, use this pseudocode:

//Takes care of RFC-3986 basic rules... but we're not done!!!!!

```
URI dirtyUri = new URI(input);  

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Rule rulePart : dirtyUri){
    //Manually rolling this in a StringBuilder probably means you'll
    //have to add in some components based on what ruleParts are available
    //but at least it has no dependencies.
    sb.append(ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(rulePart));
    //This will take care of everything but URI queries.  These are special.
}
```

3. I use Google Guava to do this, but if you didn't want dependencies, your favorite way to get a `Map<String, String>` object.
4. Once you have a map of URL Query parameters:

`Iterator<Entry<String,String>> iter = map.iterator();`

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
   Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
   sb.append(ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(entry.getKey()) + "=");
   sb.append(ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(entry.getValue());
   if(iter.hasNext()){
      sb.append("&");
   }
}
```

Once you get here, you will have a URL string that has been scanned for multiple encoding attacks, mixed-encoding attacks, and RFC-3986.  This string is safe to run regex against and avoids the issues caused by the ESAPI simplification made above.

In validation.properties you'll define

`Validator.CustomUrl={customURLRegex}`

to handle any further restrictions you want on URL data.

You would call it like this:

`validator.getValidInput("urlValidation", input, "CustomUrl", MAX_FIELD_SIZE, false)`

In this AND ONLY IN THIS CASE we turn off esapi's canonicalization on validation.  (We already did it when constructing the canonicalized string.)